# Can I view a record if that record type / page layout is not assigned to me in salesforce

Tags: security, record-type

If I have access to 2 record types of an object and someone who has an access to a 3rd record type assignes me that record (which was created using that 3rd record type), will I be able to view it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Record Types only change the page layout that is used for a given profile for that record. It does not restrict access to the record itself (this is done with Sharing Settings). If you don't have a Record Type assigned to you, you cannot create a record of that Record Type, nor can you change a record you can edit to that Record Type. In other words, yes, you will be able to see and edit the record if you are the owner of that record.

Comment: Understood. Thanks!